# Correct output activation for multiple binary outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Tensorflow in an attempt to predict the winner out of six entries in a race. I have processed the data so that there are 6 features per row for the positions, with 1 being the winner and the rest represented as 0. As a result, I'm only interested in finding out which of the 6 is predicted to win and discard the others. Ideally, the loss function would punish false positives more than anything, since that seems to be the biggest issue at the moment.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                # normalizer,
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001), activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
            ]
        )
        initial_learning_rate = 0.001
        lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
            initial_learning_rate,
            decay_steps=6000,
            decay_rate=0.96,
            staircase=True)

        METRICS = [
            tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
            tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'),
            tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
            tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
            tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='prc', curve='PR'),  # precision-recall curve
        ]

        model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
                      metrics=METRICS)
```

After not having much luck with softmax I have tried sigmoid but neither of them are producing great results. I'm wondering what the recommended output activation and loss functions are for this sort of problem?

Comment: "neither of them are producing great results" What makes you say this? Is there a specific problem?

Comment: Loss increases immediately after initialising the model. I've tried lots of different structures for layers, adding drop out and so on and the predictions don't make much sense. I'm expecting them to be between 0 and 1 so I assumed the loss function or output activation was doing something unusual.